# What Database/PostgreSQL operators for Kubernetes/8penshift are available on the market?

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, openshift, high-availability

I am looking into High availability solution for databases on Openshift/K8s in general. I did a few days of research and the list keeps getting bigger and bigger. I could not find an full list of solutions so I was wondering if you guys could help me with listing some of the options out there, so I can research each different solution.

Comment: I would suggest stolon, https://github.com/sorintlab/stolon. It passed a couple of failure scenarios I designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operatorhub could be the one you are looking for https://operatorhub.io/?keyword=postgres

More details are in the about page https://operatorhub.io/about

Quoting them

> OperatorHub.io was launched by Red Hat in conjunction with Amazon, Microsoft, and Google forming the initial group that are supporting the initiative. Together, this group leveraging their Kubernetes expertise is managing the contribution and vetting process for the Operators included in OperatorHub.io